# PHP Regex not behaving greedily when it should

Tags: php, regex

I have a potentially very large list of submit type input buttons which are named `delete0`, `delete1`, `delete2` and so on, and I'm trying to use `preg_match` to match the clicked button in the `$_POST` array and tease out the appended number, so I can delete that number from a mysql table.

The problem is that my `preg_match` is not behaving greedily when it seems it should be. For example, if I submit with button `delete13`, I'll get a match for `delete1`, with `delete23` I get a match for `delete2`, etc.

Below is my pattern and logic:

```
$pattern = "/,?(delete)(\d)+,?/";
$allpostkeys = implode(",", array_keys($_POST));
echo "<br />" . $allpostkeys . "<br />";
if (preg_match($pattern, $allpostkeys, $matches))
{
    echo "<br />You elected to delete row: " . $matches[2];
    $rowToDelete = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: You should get delete3 if the input is delete13.

Comment: Could we see the result of your echo's ?

Comment: you should use delete[] as the name for your buttons. That way it will be simpler to implement what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$pattern = "/,?(delete)(\d)+,?/";
```

into

```
$pattern = "/,?(delete)(\d+),?/";
```

Comment: Got it, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Small fix:

```
/,?(delete)(\d+),?/
```

You are capturing on a pattern that is being repeated: `(\d)+`, so only the substring from the last repetition should be left in the capturing group (a single digit). `(\d+)` will capture the substring, which contains **all** repetitions of digits.

As further improvement, the first capturing group is not necessary:

```
/,?delete(\d)+,?/
```

So you can refer to the number after `delete` with `matches[1]`